# PhoneGap not working on iOS 5 device

Tags: ios5, cordova, sencha-touch-2, phonegap-build

Hi i tried creating sample index.html with simple notification code from [Docs Phonegap Notification](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#Notification) .

I zipped the index file and uploaded it to build.phonegap.com with 2.9 version. The App is successfully installed on my iPad(iOS 5) but nothing happen when i click on Show Alert. I also tried adding phonegap 2.9.0 on my Sencha Touch 2 Application ,i build it as  native and installed it on my device but the app hangs on app Loading Indicator.

**Index.html** code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Notification Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Empty
    }

    // alert dialog dismissed
        function alertDismissed() {
            // do something
        }

    // Show a custom alertDismissed
    //
    function showAlert() {
        navigator.notification.alert(
            'You are the winner!',  // message
            alertDismissed,         // callback
            'Game Over',            // title
            'Done'                  // buttonName
        );
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><a href="#" onclick="showAlert(); return false;">Show Alert</a></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

Got things working when i add config.xml on the zip file. And added phonegap.js script inside the body tag before uploading it to build.phonegap.

Thanks

Comment: When you upload to build.phonegap, are you including a config.xml file in your .zip file? If so, please post that as well. Initial thoughts are that you are mixing phonegap calls with build.phonegap calls.

Comment: did you packaged correctly ? see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478663/how-to-run-a-sencha-touch-project-in-xcode-emulator/18479264#18479264) answer.

Comment: Got things working when i add config.xml on the zip file. And added phonegap.js script inside the body tag. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got things working when i add config.xml on the zip file. And added phonegap.js script inside the body tag.

Thanks